# Upgrading react-router-dom from Switch to Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

This worked in "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Api from "./Api";
const api = new Api();
const App = () => {
  return (

  ...
  <Router basename="/my-app">
    <Switch>
       <Route
         path="/complete"
         render={(props) => <ConfirmationPage {...props} api={api} />}
       />

       ...
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

After upgrading to "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3"

We've tried:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Api from "./Api";
const api = new Api();
const App = () => {
  return (

  ...
  <Router basename="/my-app">
    <Routes>
       <Route
         path="/complete"
         element={(props) => <ConfirmationPage {...props} api={api} />}
       />

       ...
    </Routes>
  </Router>
```

But that doesn't work. We've read through https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.3/upgrading/v5
but do not see how to handle passing in props.

Comment: What props? You access things like the location via hooks now, see https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.3/upgrading/v5#advantages-of-route-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` the route components are passed ***as JSX*** to the `element` prop, and passing props to the routed component works just like it does anywhere else in React.

Example:

```
<Router basename="/my-app">
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/complete"
      element={(
        <ConfirmationPage
          api={api} // <-- props passed to component
        />
      )}
    />
    ...
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

There are no longer any route props, so if the routed components need access to what was *previously* provided they will need to use the React hooks, i.e. `useLocation`, `useNavigate`, `useParams`, etc.

Additional documentation:

- [Why does `<Route>` have an `element` prop instead of `render` or `component`?](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#why-does-route-have-an-element-prop-instead-of-render-or-component)
- [Advantages of `<Route element>`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#advantages-of-route-element)